# how to use adb to change resolution of device

Tags: android, adb, android-resolution

I'm trying to change the resolution of devices using following command
`adb shell wm size 480x800`
but after the screen resolution changes I'm getting alert saying
`"Unfortunately, Touchwiz Home has stopped working"`

I'm using Samsung Tab 3.

Many articles are there for solving the problem, but none of them are getting this while changing resolution using `abd`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because of the pixel density of your device and screen size of your device.
When you change the resolution of your device to some different resolution, the pixel density might be more according to resolution of the screen.
As a result of this icons might fall off the screen, which will cause touch to fail.

Try to tune up the pixel density(give more than 72 and less than 110).

`adb shell wm density value_in_pxels`

This will help sure.

Answer (score 24):

Alternatively, you can use something like

`adb shell wm size 1080x1920`

and then

`adb shell wm density 390`

According to https://www.theandroidsoul.com/change-screen-resolution-adb-android/